# How to extract motion vectors from h264 without a full decode

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, libav, motion-detection

I'm want to extract the motion vector information from the encoded stream without performing a full decode of the frame. I'm using ffmpeg library and aware of extracting the information using the `av_frame_get_side_data`. Unfortunately, it does a full decode of the frame before providing the `AV_FRAME_DATA_MOTION_VECTORS`. My hunch is it should be possible to parse the h264 to extract out the motion vectors only, ignoring all the other data. Any direction/pointers will be very helpful!

Comment: With any luck, did you discovered a way to extract the motion vector without decoding

Comment: Unfortunately not. I just gave up on the idea indefinitely.